# Custom UITableViewCell for a grouped table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped table view.
I'm trying to create a custom cell using interface builder, however when I'm putting a label, or a view as a subview for the cell, and stretching it to the entire cell, when I run the app the label goes beyond the cell's dimensions.

Any reason why it would do that ? 
I tried to play with the resizing mask to no avail.
When the table is plain, there's no problem.

I guess I'm doing something wrong, cause it's not suppose to be that complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in creating UITableViewCells with IB, but I would recommend adding your subviews programmatically using a UITableViewCell subclass. Your issue is that the subviews are added directly to the UITableViewCell view, and the left and right margin are part of that view.

The UITableViewCell subview that represents the actual "active" space (the white part of the cell) is contentView. If you add a subview to contentView, then it shouldn't appear outside it. In other words, CGPointZero of contentView is the top left point of the *white space*.